# как узнать heigth всей страниц (вместе с прокруткой)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как узнать высоту всей страницы (вместе с прокруткой) от начала `header` до конца `footer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простым js:

```
var B = document.body,
H = document.documentElement,
height

if (typeof document.height !== 'undefined') {
    height = document.height // For webkit browsers
} else {
    height = Math.max( B.scrollHeight, B.offsetHeight,H.clientHeight,  H.scrollHeight, H.offsetHeight );
}
```

jquery: `$(document).height()`

Answer (score 0):

Если имеется в виду высота контента между тэгами `<header>` и `<footer>`:

```
document.querySelector('.content').clientHeight;
```

Comment: между но учитивая висоту і тово и тово

Comment: Значит ответ Konstantin Okhotnick тебе нужен.